# Cancel button in html

Tags: html, forms, cancel-button

How do you make a cancel button in a form that will return you to the home page?
I do not know where to start for it.
Tried to create it already with no good result.
Keep getting a ticked box. Any ideas?

Comment: Cancel button that return to home page? Use `<a>` link with custom style to look like button, or use button (type button) and JS to detect on click to redirect.

Answer (score 1):

*According to @vee's comment:*

**Fake button with anchor element:**

```css
a.button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;

  background: #e9e9ed;

  text-decoration: none;
  color: initial;

  border: 1px #8f8f9d solid;
  border-radius: 3px;

  padding: 2px 5px;

  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: small;
}

a.button:hover {
  background: #d0d0d7;

  border-color: #676774;
}
```

```html
<a href="/" class="button">Button</a>
```

**Real button with JavaScript click event:**

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location.href = '/';
});
```

```css
input#button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input value="Button" type="button" id="button" />
```